# Push inline math to next line without manual line break (maintain justification)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, justification

In my theorem, you can see that the placement of the math expression on the first line of the theorem is exceeding the margins.  I don't want to break the expression, and if I put a line break before it, then the justification gets messed up.  I want all the text left and right justified except and the beggining and end of a paragraph.  How do I do it?  Thanks?

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{bm}    
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} 
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5in,top=0.75in,bottom=.75in,centering,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection] 
\newtheorem{mainthm}[thm]{Main Theorem} 

\begin{document}
\large

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{mainthm}\label{thm:VecSpa}
    A maximal set of independent tangency classes $\{[\gamma'(\lambda_0)]_{(\sigma)}\}$ is a basis for a vector space $\mathcal{V}$, and a tangency class of curve derivatives $[\gamma'(\lambda_0)]$ is a vector $\bm V\in\mathcal{V}$.
\end{mainthm}
        
\lipsum[1][4-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `classes\linebreak $....`

Comment: Maybe rewording could be an option: "A maximal set $\{[\gamma'(\lambda_0)]_{(\sigma)}\}$ of independent tangency classes is"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle NICE!!!!!!!

Comment: Off-topic: `left=1.5in,right=1.5in,top=0.75in,bottom=.75in` may be expressed more succinctly as `hmargin=1.5in, vmargin=0.75in`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\\`  and `\newline` force a line break leaving a line short. `\linebreak` forces a break without  losing justification so you can use

`classes\linebreak $....`

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could insert the instruction `\sloppy` immediately after `\begin{mainthm}\label{thm:VecSpa}`. As the following screenshot demonstrates, the interword spacing can become rather, well, sloppy as a result, but justification can be maintained.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{bm}    
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} 
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5in,vmargin=0.75in,
            centering,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection] 
\newtheorem{mainthm}[thm]{Main Theorem} 

\begin{document}
\large

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{mainthm}\label{thm:VecSpa}
\sloppy % <-- new
A maximal set of independent tangency classes 
$\{[\gamma'(\lambda_0)]_{(\sigma)}\}$ is a basis 
for a vector space $\mathcal{V}$, and a tangency 
class of curve derivatives $[\gamma'(\lambda_0)]$ 
is a vector $\bm{V}\in\mathcal{V}$.
\end{mainthm}
        
\lipsum[1][4-6]

\end{document}
```